# How are the outputs of multi-select questions saved in CommCare

Tags: commcare

If I have a multi-select question with 3 possible choice values, and more than one of those is selected by the user, how is that saved to the case? Is it a string that concats the id of each choice?

Multi select question?

[ ] choice_1

[x] choice_2

[x] choice_3

Would the output be: 'choice_2 choice_3'

Answer (score 2):

It saves them as a space separated list.  So, yes, you are correct, the output would be "choice_2 choice_3".